# Solve by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following by substitution:

$$
y''(t)+y(t)=\cos(wt)
$$

I know that the general solution to the homogeneous part is $y=A\sin(t)+B\cos(t)$ for some constants $A,B$ but I am unsure which substitution to use.

Normally I would approach this using variation of parameters but the question says substitution so I am unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Try to substitute $y(t)=C\sin(\omega t)+D\cos(\omega t)$, and solve for $C$ and $D$.
For $\omega^2 \neq 1$:
$y''(t)=-\omega^2(C\sin(\omega t)+D\cos(\omega t))$, so:
$$-\omega^2(C\sin(\omega t)+D\cos(\omega t))+C\sin(\omega t)+D\cos(\omega t)=\cos(\omega t)$$
$$D\cos(\omega t) (-\omega^2+1)+C\sin(\omega t) (-\omega^2+1)=\cos(\omega t)$$
From this, we can see that $C=0$:
$$D\cos(\omega t) (-\omega^2+1)=\cos(\omega t)$$
$$D(-\omega^2+1)=1$$
$$D=\frac{1}{-\omega^2+1}$$
So the solution is $y(t)=\frac{1}{-\omega^2+1}\cos(\omega t)$.
For $\omega^2=1$, try to do the same with $y(t)=Ct\sin(\omega t)+Dt\cos(\omega t)$, as [John Ma](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/99914/john-ma) suggested it (It will require a bit more differentiation).

Comment: thank you. How did you know to use this substitution? Is it because of the solution to the homogeneous part?

Comment: No, it's because you have $\cos(\omega t)$ on the right side. So it should be some combination of $\sin(\omega t)$ and $\cos(\omega t)$.

Comment: It works for $\omega \neq \pm 1$. When $\omega = \pm 1$ one has to multiply by $t$.

Comment: Thank you @JohnMa!

Comment: I am not sure if external links are allowed but I have found what I need to get: https://prnt.sc/j5pep4 (It is a print screen of the answer). Even using your substitution I cannot seem to get what is required

Comment: @juper I added it to my answer. Is it better now?

Comment: ah yes! I made a simplification error. One last question: How do you 
know to mulitply through by $t$ for when$w \ne 1$ ? I understand that the reason for the two cases. Thank you massively for your help

Comment: @juper Sorry, I don't know it exactly. I think it has to do something with the fact that the homogenious part contains the $\omega^2=1$ cases already. I think a smarter person, like JohnMa would be able to answer this question.

Comment: No need to apologise, thank you very much for your help!